# LoadError: cannot load such file -- azure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure, rspec, paperclip

I was updated ruby and rails from 5.2 to 6.0.1 and after that, I was tried to run Rspec then get this error.

```
LoadError:
 cannot load such file -- azure
```

Also reported on GitHub here is the link:
https://github.com/supportify/paperclip-azure/issues/27

System configuration

```
Rails version: 6.1.0
Ruby version:  3.0.2
paperclip version: 5.1.0
paperclip-azure: 1.0.1
```

Comment: Please share the code to better understand the context.

Comment: @NadineRaiss please check this https://github.com/supportify/paperclip-azure/issues/27